# Is it possible to use Node-Redis in this fashion or will I stick to websockets?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, node-redis, fastify

I've been mulling over a design that involves:

1. A client making a POST request to an endpoint
2. The route then publishes (from a constructor that returns a request object which I stringify) to a redis channel. e.g.

```
( {request: String, transid: String, data: Object } )
```

3. Another server listening to that channel, parses the JSON -> switches the request key from the obj
4. Does functions like verify credentials etc;
5. Calls a Class that returns a premade response object that is converted to str, and sent back over the same (or another channel) to the route handler (that sent the original request over the channel) that is listening awaiting asynchronously (in this case, fastify.) e.g.
   `( { "transid": "1234-Abcd-5678-abcde", "state": Boolean, data: <data> } )`

**Timeline**

Route handler makes a Pub Request to redis listener:

1. `( {request: "auth", transid: "1234-Abcd-5678-abcde", data: { email: "test@test.com", "password": "pass" } )`
2. Subscribed listener on another server does internal credential validation

Publishes back to redis channel

3. `( {transid: "1234-Abcd-5678-abcde", state: false, data: { error: "Incorrect" } } )`
4. Route handler replies to client using library specific methods i.e. request.send(200)

My problem is I don't exactly understand how I can achieve the result of step 4 in the above timeline; i.e. is it even possible to almost await a message whilst in a route handler? I've gotten extremely close but I'm questioning if this is a practical way to go about things when I'm designing something that is able to scale. (User sends details to /endpoint, /endpoint route handler publishes a json message to channel, external server listening parses the message and sends it to a switch statement i.e [switch(data.request)], that calls a function that performs the DB operation, and then uses a class constructor to generate a object to send back over the redis channel to the route handler that would be awaiting the reply, to which then reply to the client.)

Could I ask if anyone has any opinions on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept behind pub/sub is decoupling and execute async tasks, but you are forcing the system to a sync style and this vanishes all his pros.

For example: if you publish the message a none of the subscribers receive it.. what do you do? Retry? - the timeout of the client is ticking, Error? - but the user wants only to log in and the database is up&running

Moreover, when the traffic goes up, the responses will become slower because you will have only one subscriber for all those messages since pub/sub is broadcast and you don't want to process your login logic twice! (I assume)

So to solve it you should implement a peer2peer logic where:
- all the subscribers receive the message
- each subscriber know each other
- one subscriber says "I will do the job"
- one "primary" subscriber says that it is ok
- the other subscribers discard the message
- the primary subscriber crash and you need an election to have a new primary..
- etc...

But this is what a message broker does or the [redis stream api does](https://redis.io/topics/streams-intro), so you don't need to implement this by yourself.
I did it in past, but Redis 5 didn't exist yet.

For these reasons, I think you should do the sync job in the sync way.
The pub/sub don't fit your usage example.

Comment: Thanks Manuel for your insight and an alternative usage direction. My previous logic was to try force redis pubsub into being a native message broker by using self-declared subscriber UID's, but I don't believe it would have been very practical once I got it scaling in the future. I do agree, maybe I was trying to force something that was natively for async. I only glanced at the stream api for 10 seconds mistakening it as some log broker completely missing the point over it serving to be a messenger broker too. Thanks again!